# libGoogleAnalytics.a linking problems with iPhone iOS4 Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios4, google-analytics

I recently upgraded to the iOS4 SDK and my app no longer compiles for the simulator, but **does** compile for the device.

This is due to the 3rd party library **libGoogleAnalytics.a**. The solution seems to be for google to release a new static library complied with the new SDK, unfortunately there is no word of any release date, and due to the new SDK licensing, they may never release a new library.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=0e35876711dc99b1&hl=en

I am getting the following compile errors:

```
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_NSObject", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_GANTCPSocket in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTCPSocket.o)
      .objc_class_name_GTMLogger in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      .objc_class_name_GTMLogBasicFormatter in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      .objc_class_name_GTMLogLevelFilter in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      .objc_class_name_GTMLogNoFilter in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      .objc_class_name_GTMLogASLWriter in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger+ASL.o)
      .objc_class_name_GTMLoggerASLClient in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger+ASL.o)
      .objc_class_name_GANDataDispatcher in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANDataDispatcher.o)
      .objc_class_name_GANHTTPResponseParser in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANHTTPResponseParser.o)
      .objc_class_name_GANEvent in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANEvent.o)
      .objc_class_name_GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      .objc_class_name_GANTracker in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      .objc_class_name_GANPersistentEventStore in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANPersistentEventStore.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSFileManager", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSFileManager in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANPersistentEventStore.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSString", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANPersistentEventStore.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSError", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSError in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSError in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANPersistentEventStore.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSFileHandle", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSFileHandle in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableString", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableString in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANDataDispatcher.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSTimer", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSTimer in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANDataDispatcher.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANPersistentEventStore.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIScreen", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIScreen in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANDataDispatcher.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSProcessInfo", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSProcessInfo in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
  "_objc_exception_extract", referenced from:
      +[GTMLogger sharedLogger] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      +[GTMLogger setSharedLogger:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setWriter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setFormatter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setFilter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[NSFileHandle(GTMFileHandleLogWriter) logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[NSArray(GTMArrayCompositeLogWriter) logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogStandardFormatter stringForFunc:withFormat:valist:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter count] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter droppedLogCount] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter reset] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter dumpContents] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      +[GANTracker sharedTracker] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      +[GANTracker allocWithZone:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker startTrackerWithAccountID:dispatchPeriod:delegate:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker trackPageview:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker trackEvent:action:label:value:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker stopTracker] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker dispatch] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSDate", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDate in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDate in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANPersistentEventStore.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIDevice", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIDevice in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANDataDispatcher.o)
  "_objc_exception_try_exit", referenced from:
      +[GTMLogger sharedLogger] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      +[GTMLogger setSharedLogger:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setWriter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setFormatter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setFilter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[NSFileHandle(GTMFileHandleLogWriter) logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[NSArray(GTMArrayCompositeLogWriter) logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogStandardFormatter stringForFunc:withFormat:valist:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter count] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter droppedLogCount] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter reset] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter dumpContents] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      +[GANTracker sharedTracker] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      +[GANTracker allocWithZone:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker startTrackerWithAccountID:dispatchPeriod:delegate:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker trackPageview:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker trackEvent:action:label:value:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker stopTracker] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker dispatch] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSDateFormatter", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDateFormatter in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
  "_objc_exception_try_enter", referenced from:
      +[GTMLogger sharedLogger] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      +[GTMLogger setSharedLogger:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setWriter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setFormatter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogger setFilter:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[NSFileHandle(GTMFileHandleLogWriter) logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[NSArray(GTMArrayCompositeLogWriter) logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLogStandardFormatter stringForFunc:withFormat:valist:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter count] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter droppedLogCount] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter reset] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter dumpContents] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      -[GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter logMessage:level:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLoggerRingBufferWriter.o)
      +[GANTracker sharedTracker] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      +[GANTracker allocWithZone:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker startTrackerWithAccountID:dispatchPeriod:delegate:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker trackPageview:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker trackEvent:action:label:value:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker stopTracker] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      -[GANTracker dispatch] in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSUserDefaults", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSUserDefaults in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSThread", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSThread in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GTMLogger+ASL.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSBundle", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSBundle in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANDataDispatcher.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSAssertionHandler", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSAssertionHandler in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANTracker.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSAssertionHandler in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANPersistentEventStore.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSLocale", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSLocale in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GANDataDispatcher.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

One suggestion on the google forum is to create a dummy implementation of the GANTracker class for use in the simulator. ie to create a file GANTracker_stub.m:

```
#import "GANTracker.h"

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

@implementation GANTracker

+ (GANTracker *)sharedTracker
{
    return [[[GANTracker alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (void)startTrackerWithAccountID:(NSString *)accountID
               dispatchPeriod:(NSInteger)dispatchPeriod
                     delegate:(id<GANTrackerDelegate>)delegate
{
}

- (void)stopTracker
{  
}

- (BOOL)trackPageview:(NSString *)pageURL
        withError:(NSError **)error
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)trackEvent:(NSString *)category
        action:(NSString *)action
         label:(NSString *)label
         value:(NSInteger)value
     withError:(NSError **)error
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)dispatch
{
    return YES;
}

@end
#endif
```

This however is not working for me, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google Analytics for iOS 0.8 SDK would resolve this problem. I just tried today.

Download it from: http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/download.html

Answer (score 3):

Solution found via the Google Analytics forum:

Use:

`lipo libGoogleAnalytics.a -remove i386 -output libGoogleAnalytics2.a`

Then delete libGoogleAnalytics.a from your project and add libGoogleAnalytics2.a

This only works in conjunction with the dummy implementation of GANTracker as shown above.

Comment: Nice find!  This one has been causing me issues too.

Comment: Would start another question, but would you kindly say just exactly *what* you did with GANTracker_stub.m?  people on the forums are saying copy the code into GANTracker_stub.m but not what to do next?  The solution with -remove i386 does not seem to me as if it would allow running under the sim?

Comment: I just created added a new file using XCode, called it GANTracker_Stub.m. Deleted the GANTracker_Stub.h file and copied the code above into it. Then when you compile your project, GANTracker_Stub.m automatically overrides the GANTracker implementation in the static library. Does that make sense?